# Note taking app with hierarchical tags for Android

Tags: android, note-taking

I'm looking for an Android app that can save notes (plain text) and is able to attach multiple tags to the note. The tags should be managed as a tree.

Some people recommend to "fake" the hierarchy by adding a seperator like an underscore for each sub level e.g. "#level1_level2“. But if you change the structure of the tree e.g. by adding a new level you have to refactor all your tags.

Hope to hear some suggestions!

Comment: Tags were invented to obviate hierarchy, not to reinforce it!

Comment: Ok so lets put it a different way. The note is like a leaf which is part of multiple trees. I want to build up different trees e.g. org charts, project plans etc. and when a new note is created, I want to associate the note with different trees resp. their leafs. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I found what I needed: it's called NoteLynX and it does much more!

You can create notes in plain text and/or with html tags in a hierarchy. Once created you can connect the notes with different relations (parent,child,friend). So one note can have a variety of links to other notes (e.g. two or more parents)

If you like you can also rebuild the network as a tree from every note. Cateorizatuon is also very easy: just create a parent note (category name) and the some subnotes (category instances).

You can find it at:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.astrodean.notelynxpro

Answer (score 0):

Workflowy is a wonderful tool that supports exactly the type of hierarchy you are looking for. Great tool, also supports tagging.

There is a web version and andriod/iphone apps.